# Visual Studio 2012 project lost link to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

So I came back to a project that I was working on a few months ago, and when I load it one of the projects seems to have lost the link to it's entry in TFS. The solution explorer doesn't show the lock icons for it, but I still see it in TFS.

I tried performing a add to source control but it says that the items already exist.

Anybody have ideas on how to fix this?

I'm trying to avoid remapping because there are a few branches, and I'm not even sure that will fix it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your solution has lost the TFS binding, you can do the following to fix it. First open the solution/project you wish to bind in Visual studio then:

1. Highlight the project or solution you wish to bind to Team Foundation version control in Solution Explorer.
2. On the File menu, click Source Control, and then click Change Source Control.
   3.In Change Source Control dialog box, click Bind.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Update for VS 2013 (thank you Caad9)** - In VS 2013 [Ultimate at least] there's an additional level in the menu; File - Source Control - Advanced - Change Source Control... which brings up the dialog

Comment: Never mind, I was confused by a message that I read too quickly. All I had to do was to click the top level solution entry to bind to the solution file

Comment: In VS 2013 [Ultimate at least] there's an additional level in the menu; File - Source Control - _Advanced_ - Change Source Control... which brings up the dialog.