# Add an existing solution to an existing project on TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I have a problem to add an existing solution to a project on TFS that I've just created. I've seen many posts on this topic how to achieve this task, but the problem is when i right click the solution there is not any "Add solution to source control" option. Also if I connect to the team explorer my solution is being automatically closed by visual studio, and the other way round.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17996354/1766402

Comment: @Isaiah4110 That's another issue, when i follow this step can't see source control option in the file menu.

Comment: Make sure you are connected to TFS in team explorere while following the steps mentioned in that answer. If you are not connected it wont show you the Source Control option

Answer (score 0):

Edit the solution file in text editor (e.g. notepad++) and remove the source control binding: Look for SourceControlProvider and remove the section it's in.

For example, in a ClearCase-bound solution, remove those three lines:

```
    GlobalSection(RationalClearCase) = preSolution
        SourceControlProvider = RationalClearCase
    EndGlobalSection
```

Same goes for each project file included in the solution. Remove all entries starting with Scc. For example:

```
<SccProjectName>Rational ClearCase</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>Rational ClearCase</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>Rational ClearCase</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>Rational ClearCase</SccProvider>
```

After editing them, the next time you open the solution in Visual Studio you will be able to add it to TFS.